# Manage interaction between actions of ember components

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which has a subcomponent which is an "editor": the subcomponent displays either a `<span>` or an `<input>`. On click of the larger component, I want to toggle editing state of the editor.

The method I first thought of is to have an action in the container component that sends action to the subcomponent. (This could be modified to have the parent's action set a property which is bound via handlebars and observed in the subcomponent -- I guess that would be closer to the "ember way" but not necessarily relevant to the problem.)

The problem is this: the editor component uses "focusOut" as a signal to stop editing. If this comes before the click then the parent's toggle of the state switched back into "editing" mode.

(Note: the editor subcomponent is used in several other places. I'd like a solution that keeps it as decoupled as possible.)

I thought of setting a "wasEditing" property in the editor, which I'd set after stopping editing, and then clear in "next". However, I guess there is no guarantee about the order of the actions? (Or even if there is, it would seem to depend on an implementation detail.)

What is the best way to resolve this? Should I go with "wasEditing" and in addition make "focusOut" idempotent (ie do nothing if already not editing)? If so, is there a good hook to use to clear "wasEditing" that is guaranteed to be after all actions?

UPDATE: based on kingpin2k's excellent example, I have implemented one solution: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punuleci/2/edit

This is based on setting a "just closed" flag, which disables re-open, then clearing after a delay. I'd prefer a better way, though, that didn't depend on an arbitrary delay.

Comment: How does the item start editing?  actions can only go out, so it'd need to be binding a property to the child component.  Here's a quick example of what I think you're saying, can you update with what you really are saying.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punuleci/1/edit

Comment: kingping2k -- excellent. In fact "actions can only go out" but I cheated and used childViews to send an action in. However -- a binding is the way to go as you say. 

Rather than a button, I want the whole outer container to toggle edit on click; your example still illustrates the problem, though: if you are focused in the editor, then click on the "edit" button we end up "still editing", as the focus out is followed by the click. I want the click to toggle the edit state -- so the focus out action should signal that the current click (only) should be ignored for starting an edit.

Comment: I edited your example with my imagined solution -- but it doesn't seem to work....  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punuleci/2/

Comment: update: modified to use "Ember.run.later( ..., 100 )" rather than "Ember.run.scheduleOnce( "destroy", ... ). I guess click comes in during the next cycle perhaps? This works but doesn't seem so nice as it relies on some arbitrary delay.